# Kafka connect transformation isn't applied

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I working in kerberised server , with distributed kafka connect. 
the connector work well, just the transformation part is totally ignored.
I have no Warn or Error or any info in logs about this problem.

My connector without transformation work well :

```
{
    "name": "hdfs-avro-sink-X",
    "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
                "tasks.max": "1",
                "topics": "Y",
                "hdfs.url": "HA_name",
                "topics.dir": "/data/path",
                "logs.dir": "/tmp/path",
                "flush.size": "8800",
                "rotate.interval.ms": "6000",
                "hive.integration": "true",
                "hive.database": "hive_db_name",
                "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://url:9083",
                "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat",
                "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD",
                "hive.conf.dir": "/usr/hdp/current/hive/target-conf/",
                "hadoop.conf.dir": "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop/target-conf/",
                "hdfs.authentication.kerberos": "true",
                "connect.hdfs.principal": "principal",
                "connect.hdfs.keytab": "/keytab/path",
                "ssl.truststore.location": "truststore.jks",
                "ssl.truststore.password": "password",
                "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
                "ssl.keystore.location": "keystore.jks",
                "ssl.keystore.password": "password",
                "ssl.key.password": "password"               
    }
}
```

with transformations, transformations is ignored :

```
{
    "name": "hdfs-avro-sink-X",
    "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
                ... same conf
                "ssl.key.password": "password",
                "transforms": "MaskField",
                "transforms.MaskField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value",
                "transforms.MaskField.fields": "ano_ass"
    }
}
```

i can type anything, it's ignored anyway :

```
{
    "name": "hdfs-avro-sink-X",
    "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
                ... same conf
                "ssl.key.password": "password",
                "transforms": "Masgfdgfdgfdhield",
                "transforms.MaskField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value",
                "transforms.MaskField.fields": "anfshdghgh_ass"
    }
}
```

ano_ass fields exist in my avro schema
no problem in ranger audit

versions :

- HDP : 2.6.4
- kafka : 0.10.1
- schema registry hortonworks

Comment: I am having the same issue with kafka version 2.8.1 (Commit:839b886f9b732b15) and
kafka docker image wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running 0.10.1 then SMT don't exist yet :) Single Message Transform were added to Apache Kafka in version 0.10.2 with [KIP-66](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect), over 2.5 years ago.

You might want to consider running a more up to date release of Kafka, the latest version of which is 2.3.

It looks like the [latest version of HDP is 3.1](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/release-notes/content/comp_versions.html) which includes Apache Kafka 2.0. If you want the latest version of Kafka (2.3) then you can get it from [kafka.apache.org](https://kafka.apache.org), and also as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).